# Adding numpy arrays via += seems to change it in place, and np.clip makes it stranger

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

While computing something, I noticed that doing addition using += on numpy arrays didn't create a new np.array and assign it to the variable on the left, but it *seems* to updat variable and references to the it. I don't recall this behaviour in the past. Adding a np.clip after the += line made things more confusing, where I can't figure out how the values are being updated.

I've attached a small working example to recreate the issue. I feel like I've never seen this happen before.

```
import numpy as np

w_l = []
w_tot = np.zeros(5)
print("array and max while making list:")
for i in range(4):
    w = np.ones(5)*0.25
    # w_tot = w_tot + w  # works as intended
    w_tot += w  # gives a view or modifies in place?
    w_tot = np.clip(w_tot, 0, 0.5)
    w_l.append(w_tot)
    print("arr", w_l[-1])
    print("max val:", max(w_tot))


print("\narray and max after list is made:")
for l in w_l:
    print("arr:", l)
    print("max val:", max(l))
```

output:

```
array and max while making list:
arr [0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25]
max val: 0.25
arr [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
max val: 0.5
arr [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
max val: 0.5
arr [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
max val: 0.5

array and max after list is made:
arr: [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
max val: 0.5
arr: [0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75]
max val: 0.75
arr: [0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75]
max val: 0.75
arr: [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
max val: 0.5
```

Tested on python3 (3.8.10), numpy '1.21.3' on Ubuntu (20.04.3 LTS)

Example on online python interpreter: https://www.online-python.com/SoyX9ufrTD

Comment: Yes, `w_tot += w` modifies `w_tot` inplace.  But `np.clip` returns an array object.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to demonstrate and comment:

```
In [49]: w_tot=np.zeros(5)
In [50]: w_l=[]
In [51]: w_tot += 1
In [52]: w_l.append(w_tot)
In [53]: w_tot += 2
In [54]: w_l.append(w_tot)
In [55]: w_l
Out[55]: [array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]), array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])]
```

Both elements of `w_l` are the same array object.  The `+=` modifies `w_tot` in place.  So [53] has modified the same object as [51].

```
In [56]: w_tot = w_tot + 1
In [57]: w_l.append(w_tot)
In [58]: w_l
Out[58]: 
[array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]),
 array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]),
 array([4., 4., 4., 4., 4.])]
```

[56] has created a new array, so the previous entries to `w_l` are not modified.

```
In [59]: w_tot=np.clip(w_tot,0,2)
In [60]: w_l.append(w_tot)
In [61]: w_l
Out[61]: 
[array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]),
 array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]),
 array([4., 4., 4., 4., 4.]),
 array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])]
```

`clip` also makes a new array.

Another in-place change:

```
In [62]: w_tot[1] = 23
In [63]: w_l.append(w_tot)
In [64]: w_l
Out[64]: 
[array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]),
 array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]),
 array([4., 4., 4., 4., 4.]),
 array([ 2., 23.,  2.,  2.,  2.]),
 array([ 2., 23.,  2.,  2.,  2.])]
```

With `numpy` arrays there's another thing to be aware of, `views`, which are different arrays, but with shared data-buffer.  This sequence of actions doesn't demonstrate that.

Comment: OK. So in my  code, += modifies in place (0.5-->0.75), clip makes a new obj (0.5), new obj gets added to list(0.5), same object is refered to in the += statement in the next loop (0.5-->0.75) so it gets modified in place in the list, then clip creates a new obj (0.5), and the cycle repeats. So the changes are explainable, but I really thought that a+=b and a=a+b had exactly the same functionality. Is it a recent change in numpy or did I just miss it?